# Closed Channel Exception copying local file system to HDFS

Tags: java, multithreading, hadoop, gzip, hadoop2

I'm trying to copy all files in a directory on the local file system to a Hadoop folder. I'm running a single node setup on my home machine with a Ubuntu VM. This is a multithreaded application (ThreadPoolExecutor) but I don't think that is causing the issue I'm experiencing. When I run it with the hdfs.close() command, I get multiple channel closed exceptions. Am I improperly closing the channels somehow?

And another issue I'm having is that these files are not compressing at all. The output files are a little bigger than the originals actually. The files are just random bytes generated from the CLI using dd. Are these file types not compressible?

```
    public void run(){

        for (int i = 0; i< f.length; i++){
            FileSystem hdfs = null;
            FileInputStream is = null;
            OutputStream os = null;
            CompressionCodec compCodec = null;
            CompressionOutputStream compOs = null;

            try{
                String fname = f[i].getName();
                hdfs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(dest), config);
                is = new FileInputStream(f[i].getAbsolutePath());
                //InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(fin);
                os = hdfs.create(new Path(dest + '/' + fname), true);
                System.out.println(dest+ '/' + fname);
                compCodec = new GzipCodec();                
                compOs = compCodec.createOutputStream(os);
                IOUtils.copyBytes(is, compOs, config);                

            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally{
                try{
                    compOs.finish();
                    IOUtils.closeStream(is);
                    IOUtils.closeStream(compOs);
                    is.close();
                    os.close();
                    //hdfs.close();
                }catch(IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

Edit: Stack trace

```
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.ExceptionLastSeen.throwException4Close(ExceptionLastSeen.java:73)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.checkClosed(DFSOutputStream.java:153)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSOutputSummer.write(FSOutputSummer.java:105)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream$PositionCache.write(FSDataOutputStream.java:57)
        at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)
        at java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.deflate(DeflaterOutputStream.java:253)
        at java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.write(DeflaterOutputStream.java:211)
        at java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream.write(GZIPOutputStream.java:145)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec$GzipOutputStream$ResetableGZIPOutputStream.write(GzipCodec.java:77)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec$GzipOutputStream.write(GzipCodec.java:118)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.copyBytes(IOUtils.java:96)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.copyBytes(IOUtils.java:68)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.copyBytes(IOUtils.java:114)
        at edu.jhu.bdpuh.hdfs.ThreadedCopy.run(ThreadedCopy.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Closing `compOs` and `is` once each is sufficient. Not several times. You don't need to close `os` at all, and you probably don't need to call `finish()` either: `close()` should do that for you. You forgot to post your stack trace.

Comment: Thanks! I have updated with the stack trace. Why doesn't the os need to be closed?

Comment: Because closing `compOs` closes the stream it's wrapped around.

Comment: It looks like `FileSystem.get()` returns a singleton that you shouldn't close. It seems to be an invariant of this loop anyway, so move its creation and destruction out of the loop and out of the threads.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I made some random text files and the compression is working fine too.